# Publishing a signed transaction using flashbots rpc takes many tries?

Tags: foundry, flashbots, sendsignedtransaction

I'm sending a signed transaction using flashbots rpc, in the following way. But often it takes many tries 2 ~ 4 times to be picked up?

```
cast publish --rpc-url https://rpc-goerli.flashbots.net/ 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
```

Comment: If this is only on goerli, there are not many people running mev boost so it can be hard to land, can easily need to target next 5 to 10 block at a time.

If you have simulated a private tx or a bundle and it should land, it is probably just that.

Comment: tested on the main net looks like this is the case! thanks!

Comment: Brilliant, good luck out there.